# Paypal Refund Rest Api v2 - Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am able to successfully execute below APIs

```
/v2/checkout/orders
/v2/checkout/orders/{order_id}/authorize
/v2/checkout/orders/{order_id}/capture
```

Why am I getting the "NOT_AUTHORIZED" response while executing PayPal refund as described here? -  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_refund

**POST request**

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/<Capture ID I got from capture request>/refund
```

**Response**

```
    {
    "name": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
    "message": "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.",
    "debug_id": "6c6xxxxx6c",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
            "field": "capture_id",
            "value": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "description": "You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource.",
            "location": "path"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v2/payments/#NOT_AUTHORIZED",
            "rel": "information_link"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sumeet, are you still facing the problem? As long as you make the call with the client_id + secret_id combination (just as you made the capture call); you should not face this issue. If you are still facing this issue; please revert back with the paypal-debug-id and we will take a look.

Comment: @TriniGeorge By default client ID doesn't have refund permission. I raised a ticket to technical support and they gave permission to my client ID and now it works.

Answer (score 9):

You have to contact the PayPal support to add permission for your existing ClientId and Client secret (which works fine for PayPal V1 APIs) for V2 Refunds and Cancel request and there is no other way you can set the permission for same.
If you need to avoid this then Just create new ClientId and Client secret from PayPal accounts and it will work fine with PayPal V2 APIs.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. Only way seems to contact the support.

Comment: This helped me, I just needed to create new API keys..... :(

Comment: I did not manage to find this documented anywhere having spent a day trying to debug this issue. Creating a new key set worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new application with a new set of client ID and secret worked for me.

Comment: it solve my problem. my problem is  https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers   Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions